# What is the .Net (C#) Apose.Cells equivalent of Excel VBA range -> ClearContents?

Tags: c#, .net, aspose-cells

I am porting some Excel VBA code to .Net (C#) using Aspose.Cells.

In the following example, the named range "SomeRange" refers
to a collection of other ranges.

```
["SomeRange"].Value = (SomeRange1, SomeRange2, SomeRange2)
```

**Here is the VBA code snippet:**

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("SomeRange")
rng.ClearContents
```

I want to iterate over all the cells in each of the sub-ranges contained in the named range "SomeRange."

What would be the Apose.Cells equivalent in .Net (C#)?

Thanks,JB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the **Worksheet.Cells.ClearContents()** method. Other useful and related methods are

```
Worksheet.Cells.ClearContents()
Worksheet.Cells.ClearFormats()
Worksheet.Cells.ClearRange()
```

*Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose*